# Datatables highlight rows beyond the first paginated page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

The Datatables plugin is giving me some issues when trying to highlight rows beyond the first paginated page.

In the JS below you will see the commented out code where I am adding the class info to all the rows. When I do this and you paginate to the other pages all the rows on the other pages are highlighted. You will also see the uncommented code below where I add the class info to all the rows but the first row but in this case when I paginate to the other pages the rows are not highlighted.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this might be happening?

**JSFiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/560/

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('table').dataTable({
        "paging": true,
        "ordering": true,
        "filter": false,
        "length": false,
        "info": false
    });

    var table = $("table").dataTable();
    var rows = table.$("tr");
    var rowsNext = table.$("tr").next();
    var cell = table.$("td:nth-child(2)");
    var cellNext = table.$("tr").next().children("td:nth-child(2)");

    /*rows.addClass("info");*/
    rowsNext.addClass("info");

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rowsNext.addClass("info")` only adds the class to the rows on the current page, and it is only run once when the page loads.

If you want to run it every time when a different page loads, you can add an event listener to the table's [draw event](https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw), like this:

```
$("table").on("draw.dt", function(){
    var rowsNext = $("table").dataTable().$("tr").next();
    rowsNext.addClass("info");
});
```

This code will be run every time a new page is drawn.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/ebRXw/567/

Comment: But why does rows.addClass("info") not work the same way? Maybe this is a new question but I need rowsNext.addClass("info") to work the same way as rows.addClass("info") .

Comment: Because `rows` has all the rows in the table.

Comment: And its just not possible to do that with .next()

Comment: That is right. Maybe you should ask a question about what you want to do with the rows instead?

Comment: I understand what's going on I am looking for a way around it. I want it to happen on load and not have it run on every table draw.

Comment: Thanks ill just need to ask a new question.

Comment: Your original question was "why this might be happening?", if this answered that question, please consider marking this answer as accepted, thanks.

Comment: `draw.dt` doesn't run initially because you need to attach event handler BEFORE initializing the data table.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Gyrocode.com, I've updated the answer and fiddle accordingly.